# Interleaving Arrays in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

In my pursuit to write code that matches todays OpenGL standards I have found that I am completely clueless about interleaving arrays. I've tried and debugged just about everywhere I can think of but I can't get my model to render using interleaved arrays (It worked when it was configuered to use multiple arrays) Now I know that all the data is properly being parsed from an obj file and information is being copied properly copied into the Vertex object array, but I still can't seem to get anything to render. Below is the code for initializing a model and drawing it (along with the Vertex struct for reference.)

Vertex:

```
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 uv;
    glm::vec3 tangent;
    glm::vec3 bitangent;
};
```

Model Constructor:

```
Model::Model(const char* filename) {
    bool result = loadObj(filename, vertices, indices);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned short), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Draw Model:

```
Model::Draw(ICamera camera) {
    GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "mvp");
    GLuint positionID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "position_modelspace");
    GLuint uvID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "uv");
    GLuint normalID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "normal_modelspace");
    GLuint tangentID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "tangent_modelspace");
    GLuint bitangentID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "bitangent_modelspace");

    glm::mat4 projection = camera->GetProjectionMatrix(); 
    glm::mat4 view = camera->GetViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 mvp = projection * view * model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].position);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(uvID, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].uv);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].normal);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(tangentID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(tangentID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].tangent);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(bitangentID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(bitangentID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].bitangent);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionID);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(uvID);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalID);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(tangentID);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(bitangentID);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to interleave arrays? You shouldn't complicate your code unless you have a clear reason for it. I assume you're doing it for some potential speed improvements; you should only do things like this if you can benchmark that it actually speed things up.. In fact, in certain environments, interleaved arrays actually make things slower.

Comment: @JariKomppa well I can't exactly bench mark this because it is not working to begin with. I realize this can be inefficient in some cases, but the goal is just to get it working for now and worry about optimization later.

Comment: Did you have it working without interleaving first?

Comment: Have you tried gDEBugger? It's fairly nice for debugging openGL issues.

Comment: @JariKomppa yep, I mentioned in the question that it was working fine with multiarrays (aside from a small lighting issue) but when I modified the code to what I think would work for interleaving, I'm coming up blank. The only modifications are to the code shown.

Comment: @Byte56 unfortunately no, I have not tried gDEBugger, I've just been using the standard VisualStudio2010 debugger and running error checking with a combination of the glGetError and glut's getErrorMessage methods.

Comment: Interleaving arrays is neither complex nor premature optimization.  Also, for the general case, it is actually the faster path and has been since the introduction of hardware T&L.  If you need special case handling then you shouldn't compromise the general case for it, IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to change your attribute pointers, specifically the offsets you have listed. `&vertices[0].position` should be `0`, `&vertices[0].normal` should be `12`, `&vertices[0].uv` should be `24`,  and so on.

Since getting the address of a struct member gives you the absolute address instead of the address relative to the beginning of the struct. `glVertexAttribPointer` is looking for the offset into your interleaved set.

```
struct Vertex {          //previousfloats * sizeof(float) = offset
    glm::vec3 position;  // 0 * 4 = 0
    glm::vec3 normal;    // 3 * 4 = 12
    glm::vec2 uv;        // 6 * 4 = 24
    glm::vec3 tangent;   // 8 * 4 = 32
    glm::vec3 bitangent; // 11 * 4 = 44
};
```

See the documentation for the `glVertexAttribPointer` [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml). The big hint being:

> *pointer*
>
> Specifies a pointer to the first component of the first generic vertex
>      attribute in the array. **The initial value is 0**.

Comment: Ah, well done, I feel a little dumb about the error being something that small (although slightly proud for just guessing at what the code should be and coming that close.) My hat is off to you and your amazing debugging skills sir.

Comment: No problem, did it actually solve the problem? Pretty nice if that was the single little thing that was wrong.

Comment: That was the exact issue. I replaced the actually (void*)int pointers with just offsetof(...) to make it a bit simpler to read, but that was my exact problem. Thanks again for your help.